# How to exclude jars permanently from classpath when run project in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

I have spring boot project in gradle and I use Intellij to run it. The problem I have is gradle plugin I use add its dependencies and when I run spring boot app, this dependencies are added to classpath as well and then I have some issues in runitme. Of course, I can remove this libraries from external libraries (in project settings) manually, but it's temporary solution, because once I refresh gradle project, they come back. Is there any solution to exclude them permanently?

Comment: A plugin should not add it's dependencies to the classpath -- it may be broken. Try a different plugin, or change to Maven, it's much much much better anyway. But, are you sure it's the plugin? Run something like `gradle dependencies` and check the output for the offending libraries. If they're there, work out how to exclude them (a standard technique in gradle, and in fact standard in most dep-management systems).

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, they're plugin dependencies... It's not easy to change to Maven right now, so maybe I try to exclude them in build script

Comment: Then they do not get added to your classpath. Show us your build script?

Comment: Maybe I was misunderstood. When I run my app from Intellij, it takes all jars from external libraries and add them to classpath. And because mentioned plugin add its dependencies to external libraries, I have them in classpath. But only when run app from Intellij. Out of Intellij everything is ok. So there is issue, to tell Intellij to exclude this jar from classpath. Not in gradle or even maven. I think so.

Comment: Intellij doesn't do anything you haven't told gradle (or maven) to do. I have used it for years with both and not once, ever, has it added dependencies from a plugin to the classpath. There could be a bug in the version of IntelliJ you're using -- it's always possible, or you could have done something wrong in your build script. I'm betting it's the latter -- I could be wrong. I won't know, and nobody can possibly advise you, until you show us your build script. If that's a problem then please delete your question because nobody can help work out what's going on without it.

Comment: I can't show you whole build script, but here is the line and plugin cause the problem `apply from: 'http://plugins.jasoft.fi/vaadin.plugin'`.
I solved it temporally by marking all unnecessary jars as provided in module settings